# Convert into 3D Modeling

Tags: python, 3d, modeling

I want to work on a self project that makes me create 3D animated environment.
Is there a way to convert cameras input into 3D Modeling with python code?

If so, How many cameras do I need ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need stereo or trinocular cameras and OpenCV.
https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

Or, you can make a 3D scanner from one camera and photogrammetry software.
https://hackaday.com/2019/04/07/get-great-3d-scans-with-open-photogrammetry/